# Is is possible to get FB profile picture without the user-id?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I have seen some of the applications get the **profile picture** from **Facebook**, **WITHOUT** using **FB Login** (these apps don't have a Social-Sign-In option, I just entered my phone number/email id as the username and the usual password and I could see my FB pic inside that application).

I know its **possible** using the **GRAPH API** but that requires login using the **FBSDKLoginButton** and then I can use all the information returned as a response to get all the data about that user. 
And I have also seen some of the StackOverflow posts saying a URL like http://graph.facebook.com/my-user-id/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1 can return the picture. 
But this results in an error.

On browser FB says (#803) Cannot query users by their username. And using NSURLSession, the error is (#-1011) Request failed: not found (404).

However, this also **requires** the **user-id** if in case i'm doing it wrong (Please correct me on this as well :P).

So, **is it possible** to **fetch** the **user profile pic** from **Facebook** using just the **email id/phone number** ?

Comment: Of course that is not possible

Comment: _“I just entered my phone number/email id as the username and the usual password”_ – if by that you mean you entered your actual Facebook login credentials into a 3rd-party app or site - then you should _report_ those apps/sites, because they are not allowed to ask for that information in the first place. If you want interact with Facebook - then use their API.

Comment: I checked the app permissions, and found that the application has access to my contacts and photos. Can this be a possibility, that the application has picked up the profile image from my own contact ( the profile pic is same as that used in Facebook)   Much thanks for the replies.